# I need to know how COMET works

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, comet

i want to implement **comet** in php...
i have idea about how **ajax** works but i tried to study about long polling server push using comet but i am facing problem to figure out how it works. so can you please help me...

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=2&ved=0CAsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F603201%2Fusing-comet-with-php&ei=iX_5Su2-F5TwmwPHxKjCCg&usg=AFQjCNHq4-KjVv0i57LZxF-Xt-BAqYq9rQ&sig2=wvcuvZpAZWsKnkpfELyeHA

Comment: Might not be actually. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are few techniques to implement the comet concept.
you may look at [Tornado](http://tornadoweb.org) (which is has a great implementation in python) or at [phomet](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2008/04/phomet-php-comet-tiny-library.html) which is a PHP implementation. Surely [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) should be your starting point

Answer (score 2):

You might find [this google hit (How to implement COMET with PHP)](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start) interesting.